# How to debug multiple files that uses an environment for packages and makefile to compile on VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, debugging, makefile

I want to debug multiple files of python code that uses makefile that compiles all of these files together, and uses an environment. VScode python debugger doesn't really do it since it only debugs one file, while the only way to run the code is using the makefile.

I tried just using the debugger on the main file but it keeps on saying that some packages don't exist, even if the environment wherein I downloaded all needed packages is activated.

Here's the makefile:

```
runable:

    chmod u+x ./run_algo.py
    chmod u+x ./run_algo.py


SPATIAL:
    export PYTHONHASHSEED=0
    ./run_spatial.py -l ES -d lcps -i 1
    export PYTHONHASHSEED=0
    ./run_spatial.py -l MS -d lcps -i 1
    export PYTHONHASHSEED=0
    ./run_spatial.py -l HS -d lcps -i 1
    export PYTHONHASHSEED=0
    ./run_spatial.py -l ES -d fcps -i 1
    export PYTHONHASHSEED=0
    ./run_spatial.py -l MS -d fcps -i 1
    export PYTHONHASHSEED=0
    ./run_spatial.py -l HS -d fcps -i 1
```

MORE CONTEXT: This is from Subhodip Biswas' code for memetic algorithms on spatial partitioning problems [SPATIAL](https://github.com/subhodipbiswas/SPATIAL) and I want to learn how his code works by using the debugging tool

Comment: `compile python` ???? show the makefile

Comment: @rioV8 I have edited the post to show the makefile

Comment: where in this makefile is any compiling?? You just run the python file `run_spatial.py` with a few arguments, why do you need to `export` `PYTHONHASHSEED` multiple times with the same value?? JUST debug `run_spatial.py` after setting a correct launch config

Comment: what is `run_spatial.py`? repo does not have this file, makefile in repo is much simpler, why is there a `__init__.py` file in the repo, it is NOT a module